# Negate user space URL in Apache

Tags: regex, apache, redirect, negate

I have a situation where I am trying to use Apache's RedirectMatch directive to redirect all users to a HTTPS URL **except** a single (Linux) user accessing there own webspace. I have found a piece of regular expression code that negates the username:

```
 ^((?!andy).)*$
```

but when I try using it in the directive:

```
RedirectMatch ^((?!andy).)*$ https://www.example.com/
```

the URL:

```
http://www.example.com/~andy/
```

still gets redirected to the HTTPS URL:

```
https://www.example.com/
```

When I want it to ignore the redirection.
I am not an expert in regular expressions (or Apache), so any help in getting this working would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Stephen

Edit:
OK, the plot thickens... if I comment out the line:

```
# RedirectMatch ^((?!andy).)*$ https://www.example.com/
```

and restart Apache, and then try the URL:

```
http://www.example.com/andy
```

I get a 404 response, which is expected. But, if I try the URL:

```
http://www.example.com/~andy
```

The redirect is triggered and I am redirected to:

```
https://www.example.com/
```

and as I said, the redirect is commented out and I have restarted the server. How can this happen? So this is not just a regex thing, it seems Apache is redirecting without instruction!

Comment: Careful: `^((?!andy).)*$` matches any string that doesn't *contain* `andy` anywhere, so it will also trigger on `randy` etc. I can't explain the behaviour you're seeing, though.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of this maybe? (Uses mod_rewrite instead of mod_alias)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/~andy(/|$) ...
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_URI} ^http:
RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://mysite.com/$1 [R=307]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This seemed to work in exactly the same way as RedirectMatch. I think user webspace must be handled differently. If I use http://www.example.com/~qwerty (not a real user webspace) the regex works and I am not redirected.